# Why is the macromolecular composition of a human cell seemingly hard to find?

Tags: biochemistry, structural-biology, proteomics

I am trying to find a 3D rendering or list of molecules by volume in a cell (originally I was searching for human, but I'll take any at this point!). I understand the open-endedness of the question: what type of cell? During which phase? Under what conditions? etc.

What I am looking for, if such a thing exists, is as accurate-as-can-be list of structures/particles/macromolecules/ions/etc by volume in the protoplasm.

"Inside a living cell" by DS Goodsell is a step in the right direction but nearly 20 years old at this point.

"Diffusion, Crowding & Protein Stability in a Dynamic Molecular Model of the Bacterial Cytoplasm" is another step in the right direction.

Anything related to this query would be appreciated!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For some components, you can find it here: http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu

Comment: Your title and question seem to be different. Your title would be off-topic as it is not about biology per se, but as it seems to be a concern I shall comment on it. The reason, I would think, is that modern biology — especially cellular and molecular biology — is not about classification. It is about understanding how things work. So why would any modern biologist do such a thing? Presumably you have a reason for wanting such a list, but I can't imagine why you would want the comparative volumes of all proteins, for example, even if this were known. Perhaps you could explain.

Answer (score 0):

The various data related to dimensions and volumes of structures\organelles\macromolecules and cells themselves could be obtained from [BioNumbers](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx?trm=mammalian%20tissue%20culture%20cell%20volume%20organelle). For example, please see in the table below the information on volumes of [COS-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COS_cells) (monkey kidney tissue):

[image]

The details can be got at [Applying systems-level spectral imaging and analysis to reveal the organelle interactome, by Valm A.M. et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28538724?dopt=Abstract)